# How to know last item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

In my `RecyclerViewAdapter`, I would like to know if this item is the last. How can I check it?

The `onBindViewHolder` only has the position value

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder userViewHolder, int position) {

       //DO SOMETHING TO THE VIEW IF THIS IS THE LAST ITEM IN RECYCLERVIEW
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

simply you can do this:

```
    if(position == myList.size()-1){/*lastItem*/}
```

Comment: If you have a long list it items in the recyclerView, this doesn't work, it only gives you the last item currently shown. As you scroll down it changes. How to get the real last item in the list, not the last item visible?

Answer (score 9):

You can use getItemCount() or the size of your adapter list.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder userViewHolder, int position) {

       if( position == getItemCount() - 1 ){
          // Your last item
       }
}
```